# How to prioritize the keywords in recommendation engine

Tags: recommendation-engine

I am building a recommendation engine for Food products.
To recommend the best products matching the user's preferences, I would like to improve the engine with prioritization algorithms/ methods.
For example, when a user set his preference as 'Organic' and 'Nut Free', the recommendation engine generates the list of the products based on those preferences keywords. so far I have made it working based on TF-IDF distance and collocation.

However, I have no idea how I can weigh the preferences to get more appropriate results.
What is the best way to prioritize the keyword inside of the recommendation engine?

In short, I want to get the result of having more 'Organic' over 'Nut Free' in this example.

Cheers